# API secret key and public key both sent to authentication service

Tags: basic-authentication, secret-key

I have a project where I am accessing a database using the HTTP protocol. The database owner has supplied a secret key and consumer key. The database documentation then instructs me to combine the two keys using a Base64Encoding of a string consisting of "Consumer key:Secret key". The output is just another string which must be included in the header when making the call to the authentication service, e.g.

```
    headers.append("Authorization","Basic YW5ndWxhci13YXJlaG91c2Utc2VydmljZXM6MTIzNDU2");
```

Is there any reason why the database provider is not just sending the formatted string in the first place, instead of all users having to make the Base64Encoding? Is there any increased security? Both the secret and consumer key were in the same email. All insights appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Thats the [basic authentication scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) Sending usernames and passwords per email is quite problematic. Especially in the same email. And even more so, if you are not able to change the password yourself. Seeing this, I'd say, your database owner doesn't really care that much about security

Comment: Sounds like your "secret key" is your password and your "consumer key" is your username and they're just providing you instructions to do plain ol' regular http authentication.  My only guess as to why they would send them separate is that so when you have a connection issue they can ask you for your "consumer key"(username) to debug the issue easier on their end.